# getting filename on Zend_View

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-view

Is it possible to get the filename of a phtml file that's been assign to Zend_View?

For instance,

i've got this on my controller

```
$this->view = new Zend_View();
```

$this->view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/views/scripts/");
$this->view->render('email/xxx.phtml');

the question is,

how do I get 'email/xxx.phtml' from the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the ViewRenderer Helper, from your controller:

```
$viewRenderer = $this->_helper->viewRenderer;
$viewScript = $viewRenderer->getViewScript();
```

take a look at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.viewrenderer.basicusage